# jQuery toggle nav css styling

Tags: jquery, css

I have a jQuery toggle nav menu as a secondary nav on a page.

I want to add a active "state" to the top level navigation. Right now there is only a "hover" state.. The active "state" should show another color from the "sprite image"..

http://awesomescreenshot.com/07c1w39kc1

I tried to use:

```
.title1 {
padding-left:15px;
height:17px;
background: url(images/arrow-toggle.png) 0 3px no-repeat !important;
cursor:pointer;
margin-bottom:3px;
color:#168716;

}
.title1 a p:hover, .on a p { 
    background:url(images/bg_subNaviArrow.jpg);
    background-position:-20px -208px;
    margin-left: -16px; 
    padding-left: 16px; 
}

.title1 p {
   color: #000;
   max-width: 167px; 
   font-size: 12px;
   padding: 1px 3px;
   font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
   font-style: italic;
}

.on {
background: url(images/arrow-toggle.png) 0 0px no-repeat !important;
}
```

Here is the jQuery code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.title1').click(function() {    

        $('.title1').removeClass('on');    
        $('.content2').slideUp('normal'); 

        if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {    
            $(this).addClass('on');    
            $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
        }

    });

});
</script>
```

Url to test page, http://planeta.se/nordcharkLast/recept-2/

Comment: This is working for me in your demo url. When you click and open the menu it adds the class on and changes the arrow to a down arrow.

Comment: Yes it works.. but I want a different hover color not the down arrow.

Comment: and on active state the arrow down....

Comment: i would use a different class for the arrow down image (arrow-down for example), and then toogleClass on the click function. Something like $('.title1').click(function() { $(this).toggleClass('.arrow-down'); $('.content2').slideUp('normal');